# Trackpad stops clicking on a Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook, touchpad

My wife has a 17" Macbook pro with a Wacom tablet and occasionally the trackpad button machine will all of a sudden stop responding.

A reboot will fix the problem, but does anyone have an idea what is causing the problem, is it a bug in the Wacom driver?

Comment: If you plug in an external mouse does that stop responding too?
Does it ever stop responding without the Wacom tablet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause has been found. There was a loose connection in the USB cable within the tablet which was causing the entire USB subsystem to go nuts.